# Passing parameters to on click jquery event from dynamic list of anchor tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a list of elements in my asp.net mvc project. Each element is part of a `ul`, and the list elements are generated based on a list in my model.

I'm trying to add a delete button to each of these elements, but I'm struggelig a bit with how to make these elements unique, for jquery to pass the correct parameters to my action later on.

Each element has its own guid, but I can't figure out how to pass these along to the `.on('click')` jquery handler.
Here's the relevant part of my razor view:

```
<ul class="panel-tasks ui-sortable">
    @foreach (RunModel run in Model.PlannedRuns)
    {
        <li>
            <label>
                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                <!--<i class="fa fa-ellipsis-v icon-dragtask"></i>-->
                <a href="@Url.Action("RunDetails", "Planning", new { runId = run.Id })"><span class="task-description">@run.Name</span></a>
                <span class="sl-task-details">@run.RunTask</span>
                <span class="sl-task-unit">@run.ConveyanceId</span>
                <span class="sl-task-location">@run.Operation.WellContract.Location, @run.Operation.WellContract.Name</span>
            </label>
            <div class="options">
                <a href="#" id="del" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
            </div>
        </li>
    }
</ul>
```

And here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#del").on("click", function (runId) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("DeleteRun", "Planning")",
                type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { runId: runId },
            error: function (msg) {
                // Error handling
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                // Success handling
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I do realize I could add `onClick` to the anchor tag passing along the id as a parameter there, but I was hoping using jquery would do the trick, like mentioned above. Also, is there a recommended approach for doing tasks like this when several html elements use the same method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `data-*` parameter on the delete button specific to that instance which you can then retrieve on click. You also need to make the delete button use a `class` attribute, otherwise they will be duplicated in the loop. Try this:

```
<div class="options">
    <a href="#" class="del" data-runid="@run.Id"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
</div>
```

```js
$(".del").on("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var runid = $(this).data('runid');
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("DeleteRun", "Planning")",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        data: { runId: runId },
        error: function (msg) {
            // Error handling
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            // Success handling
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Just one quick question before accepting this one.
Why does it matter that the delete button gets duplicated? Each element wants to have its own button.

Comment: @NicklasWinger duplication of the element is fine, it's the `id` attribute value you cannot duplicate - `id` values must be unique within a page.

Comment: Ah, of course. Might have misread your answer slightly :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can access the item clicked with $(this) in a click event (and most events).

```
$(".del").on("click", function () {
            var runId = $(this).data("runId");
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("DeleteRun", "Planning")",
                type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            data: { runId: runId },
            error: function (msg) {
                // Error handling
            },
            success: function (msg) {
                // Success handling
            }
        });
    });
```

and insert the id as `data-runId=` in the HTML:

```
 <a href="#" class="del" data-rundId="@run.Id"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></a>
```

As the delete button is a boookmark only (#) the only effect it may have is to move the page to the top. To stop that add an event parameter and call `preventdefault()` on it. (or simply return false from the event handler).

```
$(".del").on("click", function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
```

And as `Rory McCrossan` points out, you should not have duplicate `id`s on your delete buttons (use a class). Dupe ids will actually work on most browsers, but are considered a bad thing :)

Answer (score 0):

The answers using `data-` attributes are elegant and do the job. However, I would like to propose a (slightly) different approach:

```
@foreach (RunModel run in Model.PlannedRuns)
{
    <li id="@run.Id">
      ...........
    </li>
}
```

Inside the `a` elements, set your `del` id as class.

```
$(".del").on("click", function () {
    var runid = $(this).parent().id;
    //..............
});
```

The advantages of this solution:

1. Your `li` elements have an id which can be used by other JavaScript functions as well
2. No need to play around with attributes (be careful as Firefox is very picky with `data-` attributes)
3. Additionally, your delete `a` elements won't have duplicate ids.

Comment: Please qualify "`Firefox is very picky with data- attributes`"? The whole point of jQuery is to avoid cross browser issues.

Comment: `be careful as Firefox is very picky with data- attributes` so long as you follow guidelines for naming data attributes (ie. all lowercase) then I would say this is not true.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I totally agree. But that's a condition less to worry about. I'm all for `data-` attributes but Firefox is the only browser which does not "support" the full semantic of capital letters. Please note that this is entirely my point of view.